# Applying ImageMagick operators in a specific sequence

Tags: imagemagick

I have two images that are 2048x1638 which I want to append together in the following manner:

```
save(append(crop(image1.jpg, geometry), image2.jpg), image3.jpg)
```

that is, I want to perform this sequence of operations:

- crop image1.jpg to geometry
- append the result of the crop to image2.jpg
- save the result of the append to image3.jpg

Is there a way to do this?

I've looked at the [usage guide](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/) and tried

```
convert image1.jpg -crop 2048x819+0+105 -append image2.jpg image3.jpg
```

but it doesn't do the crop, and if I rearrange the order

```
convert -append -crop 2048x819+0+105 image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg
```

then it crops both images and then appends them.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, I was almost there; this works:

```
convert image1.jpg -crop 2048x819+0+105 image2.jpg -append  image3.jpg
```

and it looks like parentheses (escaped at shell) can localize operators if needed:

```
convert \( image1.jpg -crop 2048x819+0+105 \) image2.jpg -append  image3.jpg
```

Comment: That's correct, though you would be more likely to want to localise the cropping to the second image in general because the crop only applies to images already loaded. In your second example, the crop won't affect the second image anyway because it is not loaded when the crop is executed.

Comment: So to crop just the first image, use `convert image1 -crop ... image2 ...`

Comment: To crop both, use `convert image1 image2 -crop ...`

Comment: To crop just the second, use `convert image1 \( image2 -crop ... \) ...` Or use `convert image2 -crop image1 +swap ...`